# Getting unlogged after a redirect in django

Tags: django, django-views, django-authentication

I have 2 Django projects :

- `project_redirect`, which is running on http://localhost.com:8005
- `project_logged_in`, which is running on http://localhost.com:8000 (I'm authenticated in this one)

When I try to do a redirect from `project_redirect` to a view that requires authentication in my `project_logged_in`,  I get unlogged in `project_logged_in` (checked that with `request.user.is_authenticated()` in the first line of the view).

my redirect view is as sample as :

```
def test_redirect_view(request):
    return HttpResponseRedirect('http://localhost.com:8000/login_required_view/')
```

Why would this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your session cookie is being shared by both projects as they are using the same domain.

Try setting [`SESSION_COOKIE_NAME`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/) in both projects to something unique.